# How to divide a result column by another column in an existing table? (mysql)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, resultset

I have two tables currently:

1. tb (columns are: country, year, sex, child, adult, elderly)

2.population (columns are: country, year, population)

I need to find the rate of total cases/population and display that result. I added up the total cases by country by year as 'Total' but that is just a result, not part of any table. Here is the code I used to sum up the cases:

```
SUM(IFNULL(child, 0)+ IFNULL(adult, 0) + IFNULL(elderly, 0)) AS Total
FROM tb
GROUP BY year, country;
```

Now I need to divide that result 'Total' by the 'population' column. How can I do that?

Comment: Are the combinations `country/year` unique in any of both tables?

Comment: You are on the right track! You can use a result column of a _sub_ query exactly as if it was a column of a "real" table (performances aside). You just need to find a way to 
_join_ your current query with the population table :)

Comment: Country and year are all the same values in both tables. What I am stuck on is how to reference the query result column 'Total' to join it with population table.